# Matching multiple tables get role name

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to match Project.user_Id to User.id and User.role_Id to Role.id.
From here get all the Role.name where Project.Assignment_id = 1.

```
Table1 - Project
id
assignment_Id
user_Id

Table2 - User
id 
role_Id

Table3 - Role
id
name
```

What is the laravel eloquent way of writing?

```
SELECT *
FROM Project, User, Role
INNER JOIN Project.user_Id ON User.id
INNER JOIN User.role_Id ON Role.id
WHERE Project.Assignment_id = 1;
```

I will the store it in a variable and pass it to view. 
$getRoleNames = 'DB:Table ...'
->get()

```
@foreach($getRoleNames as $getRoleName)
{{ $getRoleName ->name }}
@endforeach
```

Here I achieve getting all role name from Project.Assignment_id = 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Select * from Project
    Inner Join User on Project.user_id = User.id
    Inner join Role on Role.id = User.role_id
    Where Project.Assignment_id = 1;
```